# No resource found when using '@string/value' in layout.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

just started programming android and I am trying to make a simple `xml` file but it seems it got some problem with the `android:text=@string/..`

I have got this error:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text'
>   with value '@string/  false_button').

For each of the strings..

The code is:

> ```
> <LinearLayout 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>   android:gravity="center"
>   android:orientation="vertical" >
>     <TextView 
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding= "24dp"
>         android:text="@string/question_text"/>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/true_button"/>
>         <Button 
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/false_button"/>        
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Have you declared false_button in string.xml

Comment: for now simply try using a normal string instead of `@string/false_button` and see if that works. Use :           `android:text="False"/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the resources that you want to reference in your layout in `strings.xml` under `res/values/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="true_button">True Button</string>
    <string name="false_button">False Button</string>  
</resources>
```

`@string/true_button` refers to a resource in strings.xml

You can also have hardcoded string but not recommended

```
android:text="True Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following to your string.xml file under values folder

```
 <string name="true_button">true</string>
 <string name="false_button">false</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are created string value with the name of `false_button` in the `string.xml`

```
<string name="false_button">false</string>
```

or just give name within the quotes `""` in the `android:text` attribute

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="true_button"/>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="false_button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on res folder then click on values and then open strings.xml and add following content.

```
<string name="true_button">whatever text you want to write to your button</string>
<string name="false_button">whatever text you want to write to your button</string>
```

and save your file. Then clean your project by clicking Project -> clean and then run it again.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in `res/values/`

you have all the resources present there as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="true_button">True</string>
    <string name="false_button">False</string>  
</resources>
```

otherwisely you can hardcode values  at yours layout where you specified button as

`android:text="True "/>` or `android:text="False"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this in your `Strings.xml` class

just add `<string name="false_button">False Button</string>` line in your strings.xml
so that it will look like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

 <string name="false_button">False Button</string>  
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your android project, look for the `res` directory. Open it and inside it look for `values` directory. In values, open `strings.xml` and check if it has a `flase_button` value stored in it . If not you can add a new value using name as `false_button` and value as what you want to display on the button.

When you open the `strings.xml` in IDE like eclipse, you can switch views of the .xml file by selecting proper tab given at the bottom of your eclipse screen. Select strings.xml view and 
modify the current strings.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app</string>
    <string name="false_button">FALSE</string>
</resources>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All of these responses that refer to adding the string to the `string.xml` file make sense and work, but fail to address the original problem:  this book *("Big Nerd Ranch: Android Programming")* goes through these steps one at a time, mentions referencing the string in the layout XML file, but fails to mention adding to the `strings.xml` file.  Fail.